# The Zxing scanner does not start when the activity is restarted

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, application-restart

I'm programing an app where the user receive the information when they scan a QR code.

My problem is when I want to use the scanner again. The first time the activity starts has no problems, it works well. When I leave the activity and go back to this one it does not scan, they get all white.

I think the problem is in the process of restarting the activity, either on the `onRestart` or `onStart` methods ... I may be wrong.

This is the scanner activity code:

```
public class EscanerQrActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    public String code;
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_escaner_qr);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        zXingScannerView = (ZXingScannerView) findViewById(R.id.scanner);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        code = result.getText();
        saveLocal(readQRCode(code, 0)); //Guarda referencia QR del Local
        saveID(readQRCode(code, 1)); //Guarda referencia QR del ID de la mesa
        //Vibrar
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(200);
        startActivity(new Intent(EscanerQrActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public String readQRCode(String s, int i){//i=0 Local ; i=1 IdMesa
        String [] parts = s.split("=="); //obtiene las partes
        String [] p = parts[0].split("//"); //limpia la primera parte
        parts[0] = p[1];
        return parts[i];
    }
    public String verificarQRCode(String s, int i){//i=0 Enlace BD
        String [] parts = s.split("Locales");
        return parts[i];
    }
    private void saveID(String qr){
        try { OutputStreamWriter fout= new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("QR.IdMV", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            fout.write(qr);
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna");
        }
    }
    private void saveLocal(String qr){
        try { OutputStreamWriter fout= new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("QR.Local", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            fout.write(qr);
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any contribution.

Comment: All posts here are required to be in english. If you can't/won't translate, you can alternatively ask on [pt.so] or [es.so] depending on what language that i specifically.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was Stack Overflow en español.. anyway I translated it.